# Regluar Expression to edit Port Number List NotePad++

Tags: notepad++

I have been searching for a solution on here for sometime and tried a few different solutions similar to my issue, but to no success.

I have a list of Switch Ports and they are all formatted like this:

```
SWITCHKANSASAS01WAN1008
```

`1008` where `1` is the stack number, `0` is the slot and `08` is the port.

My end result I am hoping to achieve is:

```
SWITCHKANSASAS01.cus.nb.mac.net/1 (Where this one is the first number after WAN).
```

Then split the three remaining numbers after `WAN (008)` to look like this:

- `GigaEthernet 0/8` (drop that zero)

or if it was `10` instead of `08`:

- `GigaEthernet 0/10`

Final print out to look like:

```
SWITCHKANSASAS01.cus.nb.mac.net/1 GigaEthernet 0/8
```

or if it was 10 not 08 GigaEthernet 0/10

I tried doing each step one at a time, but it kept getting more messed up.

I am new to Regular Expressions, so I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A zero went missing in there somehow, and I don't fully understand your logic for taking `1008` and coming up with `/1 GigaEthernet 0/8`.

Comment: Oh, it is just because the spreadsheet I want to eventually compare this data to lists any ports from 1-9 as gigaEthernet 0/1 or 0/2 not 0/01 or 0/02. So I wanted to remove them to match.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `WAN(\d)(\d)0?(\d{1,2})`
- Replace with: `.cus.nb.mac.net/$1 GigaEthernet $2/$3`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
WAN         : literally
(\d)        : group 1, 1 digit
(\d)        : group 2, 1 digit
0?          : 0 or nothing
(\d{1,2})   : group 3, 1 (if there is a 0 before) or 2 digits (else)
```

Given an input like:

```
SWITCHKANSASAS01WAN1008
SWITCHKANSASAS01WAN1010
```

We got:

```
SWITCHKANSASAS01.cus.nb.mac.net/1 GigaEthernet 0/8
SWITCHKANSASAS01.cus.nb.mac.net/1 GigaEthernet 0/10
```